# Python [x::y] slice operator - why doesn't work for me?

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a list like this:

```
residL=['M', 'P', 'P', 'M', 'L', 'S', 'G', 'L', 'L', 'A', 'R', 'L', 'V', 'K', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'G', 'R', 'H', 'G', 'S', 'A', 'L', 'H', 'W', 'R', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'V', 'L', 'L', 'V', 'I', 'V', 'L', 'L', 'A', 'G', 'S', 'Y', 'L', 'A', 'V', 'L', 'A']
```

Desired output:

```
residL = ['M', 'P', 'P', 'M', 'L', 'S', 'G', 'L', 'L', 'A\n10', 'R', 'L', 'V', 'K', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'G', 'R', 'H\n20', 'G', 'S', 'A', 'L', 'H', 'W', 'R', 'A', 'A', 'G\n30', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'V', 'L', 'L', 'V', 'I', 'V', 'L\n40', 'L', 'A', 'G', 'S', 'Y', 'L', 'A', 'V', 'L', 'A\n50']
```

I can get this output with this piece of code:

```
for i in range(9,len(residL), 10):
    residL[i] = '%s\n%i'%(residL[i], i+1)
```

But I wanted to go fancy, so I tried the slice operator:

```
residL[9::10] = [x+'\n%i'%(residL.index(x)+1) for x in residL[9::10]]
```

I got a strange result though:

```
residL = ['M', 'P', 'P', 'M', 'L', 'S', 'G', 'L', 'L', 'A\n10', 'R', 'L', 'V', 'K', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'G', 'R', 'H\n20', 'G', 'S', 'A', 'L', 'H', 'W', 'R', 'A', 'A', 'G\n7', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'V', 'L', 'L', 'V', 'I', 'V', 'L\n5', 'L', 'A', 'G', 'S', 'Y', 'L', 'A', 'V', 'L', 'A\n10']
```

I'm wondering how could it be fixed. Just for the sake of learning. :)

Comment: This would be a little easier to read if you picked smaller lists and slices for your example. There's nothing else wrong with the question though, so you have an upvote from me.

Comment: `lst.index(x)` returns the index of the **first** occurrence of `x` in `lst`!

Comment: I'm always forgetting this -_- Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index` is finding an earlier appearance of the same letter. Instead, use `enumerate` to track the index yourself.

```
residL=['M', 'P', 'P', 'M', 'L', 'S', 'G', 'L', 'L', 'A', 'R', 'L', 'V', 'K', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'G', 'R', 'H', 'G', 'S', 'A', 'L', 'H', 'W', 'R', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'V', 'L', 'L', 'V', 'I', 'V', 'L', 'L', 'A', 'G', 'S', 'Y', 'L', 'A', 'V', 'L', 'A']
residL[9::10] = [x+'\n%i'%((i+1)*10) for i, x in enumerate(residL[9::10])] 
residL
# => ['M', 'P', 'P', 'M', 'L', 'S', 'G', 'L', 'L', 'A\n10', 'R', 'L', 'V', 'K', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'G', 'R', 'H\n20', 'G', 'S', 'A', 'L', 'H', 'W', 'R', 'A', 'A', 'G\n30', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'V', 'L', 'L', 'V', 'I', 'V', 'L\n40', 'L', 'A', 'G', 'S', 'Y', 'L', 'A', 'V', 'L', 'A\n50']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `enumerate` to keep track of `index`

```
>>> [x if (i-9)%10 else x+f'\n{i+1}' for i,x in enumerate(residL)] 
['M', 'P', 'P', 'M', 'L', 'S', 'G', 'L', 'L', 'A\n10', 'R', 'L', 'V', 'K', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'G', 'R', 'H\n20', 'G', 'S', 'A', 'L', 'H', 'W', 'R', 'A', 'A', 'G\n30', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'V', 'L', 'L', 'V', 'I', 'V', 'L\n40', 'L', 'A', 'G', 'S', 'Y', 'L', 'A', 'V', 'L', 'A\n50']
```